# Cram bond appears off-centered

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I have angled cram bond to a node with multiple atoms which appears off-centered as seen below with the hydroxyl  group. Is there any adjustments so I can have the bond directed to the center of the first atom instead of the middle of the top border, like what was done with the side group?

```
\documentclass[border=1pc]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2.5em,bond join = true, angle increment= 30} 
\chemfig{R>[:55,1.25]P(=[4]O)(=[2]O)<:[:-55,1.25,1]O\textcolor{red}{H}}
\end{document}
```

[image: phosphoric acid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1pc]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2.5em,bond join = true, angle increment= 30} 
\chemfig{R>[:55,1.25]P(=[4]O)(=[2]O)<:[:-55,1.25,1]O|\textcolor{red}{H}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see it now (page 44 of the documentation)